# FluentValidation's NotNull property is not working properly

Tags: maui, fluentvalidation

#### Validation rule:

```cs
RuleFor(_ => _.SeverityType)
    .NotNull()
    .When(_ => _.ObservationType != null && _.ObservationType.IsInViolation)
    .WithMessage("Severity Type is required.");
```

---

#### MSTest test case:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void SeverityType_ShouldNotHaveError_WhenNull()
{
    // Arrange
    var validator = new ViolationItemValidator();
    var observationType = new Business.Models.Violations.ObservationType { IsInViolation = true };
    var violationItem = new ViolationItemViewModel 
    { 
         SeverityType = null, 
         ObservationType = observationType 
    };

    // Act
    var result = validator.TestValidate(violationItem);

    // Assert
    result.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(_ => _.SeverityType);
}
```

Now though the SeverityType is null the test case is failing. Gives this result:

### SeverityType_ShouldNotHaveError_WhenNull threw exception:
FluentValidation.TestHelper.ValidationTestException: Expected no validation errors for property SeverityType

Validation Errors:
[0]: Severity Type is required.

This same happen in Page as well, where I'm trying to update button visibility based on the Validation rules.

The button is not getting enabled though SeverityType is null. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You are making the wrong assertion. Your validator says the severity type should **not** be null when the observation type is in violation. The test case sets the severity type to null and the observation type to be in violation. The test asserts that the validation should Should**Not**HaveValidationErrorFor --- change that to **Should**HaveValidationErrorFor. The assertion is wrong.